# Создание новых объектов при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: python, tkinter

Как мне сделать, чтобы каждое нажатие на кнопку я получал новый объект? Сейчас у меня они накладываются друг на друга

```
def get_random_int(event):
    print(event)
    int_label = Label(window, text=randint(1, 100), font='Roboto 20', fg='Black')
    int_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, anchor='n')


button = Button(window, text='Сгенерировать случайное число', font='Roboto 20', fg='Black')
button.bind('<Button-1>', get_random_int)

button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Я вас правильно понял? Вам надо создавать всегда новый объект в новом местоположение?

Comment: местоположение должно быть то же самое, объект новым. Сейчас они просто накладываются друг на друга

Comment: Так что вы ожидаете в результате? У вас создается новый объект и накладивается поверх старого.

Comment: @yangsanya `местоположение должно быть то же самое, объект новым` так у вас так и происходит - создается новый объект в старом месте. Это то же самое что "накладываются друг на друга". Может вам нужно создать один Label и просто менять в нем текст, а не создавать новые?

Comment: Либо сначала удалять старый объект, потом создавать новый, но просто менять текст как-то более логично.

Answer (score 0):

from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import random

width = 500
height = 500

class Random:
def **init**(self):
super(Random, self).**init**()
self.win = Tk()
self.win.geometry(f"{width}x{height}")
self.win.title = "Random"
self.win.minsize(width=400, height=400)
self.win.configure(bg="#778899")
self.pos = 0
self.f = 0

```
    def run():
        f = 1

        for i in range(f):
            self.f = + 1
            self.pos = self.pos + 1
            self.lis = ("Text-1", "Text-2", "Text-3", "Text-4", "Text-5")
            self.random_text = random.choice(self.lis)
            self.lbl1 = Label(self.win, text=self.random_text)
            self.lbl1.grid(row=self.pos, column=1)

            self.random_integer = random.randint(0, 999)
            self.lbl2 = Label(self.win, text=self.random_integer)
            self.lbl2.grid(row=self.pos, column=3)

    self.btn1 = Button(self.win, text="Сгенирировать", command=run)
    self.btn1.grid(row=0, column=2)

    self.win.mainloop()
```

if **name** == '**main**':
r = Random()

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: код не правильный изначально

Comment: _код не правильный изначально_, ну если ваш код неправильный, то просто удалите ответ.

Comment: По сути ваш ответ отличается от кода в вопросе только добавлением импортов, `window = Tk()` и другим способом вызова radnint. Я очень сомневаюсь, что этот ответ решает проблему, озвученную в вопросе.

Comment: извиняюсь не то скопировал все исправлю)